# numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute labels_

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I am working on Kmeans clustering algorithm. When I try to access the cluster labels it is showing:

> numpy.ndarray object has no attribute labels_

My code is as follows:

```
movies=np.array(movies)
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=19).fit_predict(movies)
print(kmeans.labels_)
```

Comment: Use `print dir(kmeans)` to get a list of all the attributes available in the `kmeans` object

Answer (score 3):

`kmeans` isn't a `KMeans` object as constructed.  `fit_predict` returns an array (which is equivalent to `labels_` of the object).  You want something like:

```
movies=np.array(movies)
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=19)
kmeans.fit(movies)
print(kmeans.labels_)
```

Or even just `print(kmeans)` instead of `print(kmeans.labels_)` in your original code.